# PyCharm does not show Qiskit vizualization

Tags: python, pycharm, qiskit

I cannot get a histogram from `Qiskit` to show using `PyCharm`, even though I am getting the numbers correctly. Code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit.providers.aer import QasmSimulator
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

simulator = QasmSimulator()
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
circuit.h(0)

# Add a CX (CNOT) gate on control qubit 0 and target qubit 1
circuit.cx(0, 1)

# Map the quantum measurement to the classical bits
circuit.measure([0,1], [0,1])
compiled_circuit = transpile(circuit, simulator)
job = simulator.run(compiled_circuit, shots=1000)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(compiled_circuit)
print("\nTotal count for 00 and 11 are:",counts)
plot_histogram(counts)
```

I should be getting an image like:

[image: this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plot_histogram` uses Matplotlib to show the histogram. PyCharm offers the option for rendering [Matplotlib graphs in Scientic Mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-support.html#scientific-project), which **only exists in PyCharm Professional**.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot to add plt.plot() after plot_histogram(counts). Also you are plotting integer counts instead of probabilities. I have added the circuit plot to the code.

> 

```
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile, Aer
# from qiskit.providers.aer import QasmSimulator
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


simulator = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
circuit.h(0)

# Add a CX (CNOT) gate on control qubit 0 and target qubit 1
circuit.cx(0, 1)

# Map the quantum measurement to the classical bits
circuit.measure([0,1], [0,1])

circuit.draw(output='mpl')

plt.show()

compiled_circuit = transpile(circuit, simulator)
job = simulator.run(compiled_circuit, shots=1000)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(compiled_circuit)
print("\nTotal count for 00 and 11 are:",counts)
plot_histogram(counts)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added the code to plot probabilities instead of integer counts.

> 

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile, Aer
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


simulator = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
circuit.h(0)

# Add a CX (CNOT) gate on control qubit 0 and target qubit 1
circuit.cx(0, 1)

# Map the quantum measurement to the classical bits
circuit.measure([0,1], [0,1])

circuit.draw(output='mpl')

plt.show()

compiled_circuit = transpile(circuit, simulator)
job = simulator.run(compiled_circuit, shots=1000)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(compiled_circuit)
print("\nTotal count for 00 and 11 are:",counts)

probs = counts
for key in probs.keys():
    probs[key] /= 1000.0
plot_histogram(probs, color='midnightblue', title="New Histogram")

plt.show()
```

> Blockquote